# What could be the cause of the error?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing code to fetch data from the database but it keeps on flagging the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: word in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Zubby\admin\updateword.php on line 7

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    $word = $_POST['word'];

    include '../include/config.php' ;
    $sql = "SELECT FROM word WHERE word = $word";

    $fetch = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    if ($fetch) {
        echo $word;
    }else{
        echo "No such word exists in the database";
    }

?>

<form name="word-Add" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="word" placeholder="  Type the Word "><br><br><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search Word"><br><br><br><br>

</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: Your missing {} around the section after `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: You also should come up with a more descriptive title.

Comment: Your SQL is invalid. Strings need to be quoted in SQL. You also will be open to SQL injections. Parameterize.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $word = $_POST['word'];

    include '../include/config.php' ;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM word WHERE word = '".$word."'";

    $fetch = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    if ($fetch) {
        echo $word;
    }else{
        echo "No such word exists in the database";
    }
}

?>

<form name="word-Add" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="word" placeholder="  Type the Word "><br><br><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search Word"><br><br><br><br>

</form>
```

Please note though that your code is highly insecure! Never use user input directly in a query! Better use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: How about giving the answer with the parameterized query?  It would solve the problem and show the right way to do it.